Linking AWS API Gateway with App Mesh on ECS
I'm trying to link AWS API Gateway with my ECS App Mesh and not cannot seem to make it work.
Specifically, I created a VPC link targeting the subnets used by the ALB currently serving as the entry point for my mesh. For the Security Groups associated with the VPC link, for testing purposes, created and associated one where I enabled all traffic for both ipv4 and ipv6. I then created an http api, along with a route for ANY request on /{proxy+} and created an integration targeting the said ALB and associated it with my VPC link. Basically following this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5368248/How-to-Configure-AWS-HTTP-API-Gateway-for-ECS-with.
Now each time I am trying to reach my mesh service from the api invoke url (both in https and http), the thing hangs and spills and {"message":"Internal Server Error"} when trying https and connection refused when trying from http. Any thoughts on how I could debug this?
Worth mentionning, I currently have no issue accessing the mesh through the ALB. Of course, once this will be working, I will switch the ALB subnets for the private ones and will put some further restrictions on the ALB SG such that they only accept traffic coming from the VPC link SG.
I tried widening the inbound rules on the ALB SG, suspecting they might prevent the incoming traffic from the VPC-Link. I also tried to associated more security groups to the VPC link, with no success.

Probably better to ask on [sf], as this isn't a programming question. Also, when you do post there, be sure to include all details - nobody should need to read an external article to understand the problem or solution.

Thanks, will indeed post there. Thank you!
